# Cannot find name 'paramMap'

Tags: angular

I am following an online tutorial and have copied the code below which appears to work for the tutor fine but I am getting an error message:

> Cannot find name 'paramMap'.

I can't seem to find a solution online.

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { News } from '../news.model';
import { NewsService } from '../news.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ParamMap } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
selector: 'app-news-detail',
templateUrl: './news-detail.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./news-detail.page.scss'],
})
export class NewsDetailPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
news: News;
private newsSub: Subscription;

constructor(
private NewsService: NewsService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.newsSub = this.NewsService.getNews(paramMap.get('newsId')).subscribe(news => {
  this.news = news;
});

}
ngOnDestroy() {
if (this.newsSub) {
this.newsSub.unsubscribe();
}
}}
```

any ideas would be hugely appreciated, many thanks in advance.

the tutorial code is

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {
NavController,
ModalController,
ActionSheetController
} from '@ionic/angular';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { PlacesService } from '../../places.service';
import { Place } from '../../place.model';
import { CreateBookingComponent } from '../../../bookings/create-    
booking/create-booking.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-place-detail',
templateUrl: './place-detail.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./place-detail.page.scss']
})
export class PlaceDetailPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
place: Place;
private placeSub: Subscription;

constructor(
private navCtrl: NavController,
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private placesService: PlacesService,
private modalCtrl: ModalController,
private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController
) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
  if (!paramMap.has('placeId')) {
    this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/places/tabs/discover');
    return;
  }
  this.placeSub = this.placesService
    .getPlace(paramMap.get('placeId'))
    .subscribe(place => {
      this.place = place;
    });
});
}

onBookPlace() {
// this.router.navigateByUrl('/places/tabs/discover');
// this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/places/tabs/discover');
// this.navCtrl.pop();
this.actionSheetCtrl
  .create({
    header: 'Choose an Action',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Select Date',
        handler: () => {
          this.openBookingModal('select');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Random Date',
        handler: () => {
          this.openBookingModal('random');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel'
      }
    ]
  })
  .then(actionSheetEl => {
    actionSheetEl.present();
  });
}

openBookingModal(mode: 'select' | 'random') {
console.log(mode);
this.modalCtrl
  .create({
    component: CreateBookingComponent,
    componentProps: { selectedPlace: this.place, selectedMode: mode }
  })
  .then(modalEl => {
    modalEl.present();
    return modalEl.onDidDismiss();
  })
  .then(resultData => {
    console.log(resultData.data, resultData.role);
    if (resultData.role === 'confirm') {
      console.log('BOOKED!');
    }
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
if (this.placeSub) {
  this.placeSub.unsubscribe();
}
}
}
```

have I missed something?

Comment: This code can't work, paramMap is not defined. Are you sure that's the final code of the tutorial?

Comment: I don't see any `paramMap` defined in your code. There is a `ParamMap` imported, but as typescript is case sensitive these are two different things. And I'm not sure if this `ParamMap` is in fact that thing you want to use

Comment: thanks for looking, I have added the tutorial code, prob I have missed something! Some of the code hasn't been covered yet so I have included yet.

Comment: `ParamMap` is the type of `this.route.paramMap`. `paramMap` is also the parameter of the callback function.

Comment: ah thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because skipped the part that provided that `paramMap` parameter in your tutor's code. And it doesn't have to be named `paramMap`. Its just a parameter - you can name it anything you want. Notice I named it `xyz` in my following code.

The `ActivatedRoute` has a property called `paramMap`, and if you subscribe to it (call the `subscribe()` method on it) you will receive any changes in the route parameter. You didn't add the `ActivatedRoute` in your code and skipped subscribing to its `paramMap`.

Add a `ActivatedRoute` service to your constructor -

```
constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private NewsService: NewsService
) { }
```

Then modify the `ngOnInit` method like below -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(xyz => {
        this.newsSub = this.NewsService.getNews(xyz.get('newsId')).subscribe(news => {
            this.news = news;       
        })
    });
}
```